# Conditional probability with merged Poisson processes

Tags: conditional-probability, poisson-process

Assume spam and non-spam email arriving in an inbox can be modelled as two Poisson processes $\{N_1\}$ and $\{N_2\}$ with hourly rates $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively.

I am asked to compute the probability that in the next hour three non-spam email will arrive, knowing that $4$ emails have arrived.

I am aware that I can merge the two Poisson processes to obtain another Posson process with rate $\lambda + \mu$; however, I am stuck at this point.

Can anyone give me any help? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Think about what happens when you condition on $n=4$, that is fixed number of trials. You have two potential outcomes that can be labeled as 0 spam 1 non spam.

Comment: It might be useful to note that over time the proportion of emails which are spam will tend to $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$ and that are   not spam to $\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}$